# How to write Django ApiView that returns a Boolean based on presence of model?

Tags: django, api, django-class-based-views

I am using Django's native Authorization/Authentication model to manage logins for my WebApp. This creates instances of the `User` model.

I would like to write a simple class-based-APIView that can tell me if a specific email is already used (IE: Is there already a user with the given email in my database?). Which generic view should I inherit from and what would the view look like?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try something like:

#### view

```
class MyView(View):
    ...
    def post(self, request, email_address, *args, **kwargs):
        response_data = {}
        if User.objects.filter(email=email_address).exists():
             response_data['result'] = 'success'
             response_data['message'] = 'email exists'
        else:
             response_data['result'] = 'failed'
             response_data['message'] = 'Email does not exist'
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

#### url:

```
url(r'^something/(?P<email_address>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$',MyView.as_view()),)
```

Comment: Isn't there any advantage to inheriting from generics.APIView instead of simply from View?

Comment: Well there are certainly some advantages for APIView(django-rest-framework), for this kind of simple task, Using `View` class should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to write a simple class-based-APIView that can tell me if
>   a specific email is already used (IE: Is there already a user with the
>   given email in my database?). Which generic view should I inherit from
>   and what would the view look like?

Sometimes, simple is best:

```
import json

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model()

@require_http_methods(['GET'])
def check_email(request, email=None):
   e = get_object_or_404(get_user_model(), email=email)
   return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'result': 'Found'}),
                       content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: No inheriting from generics.APIView? Will this work properly when I turn on memcaching?

Comment: Yes, what would memcaching have to do with this?

Comment: This is a purposely simplistic example. Now instead, suppose that I would like an API that returns the User object with the matching email (if it exists). The first time this API is called, it should get the User object from the DB. But subsequent times it is called, it should return it from the Memcache (if and only if, the underlying row in the database is unchanged). How can I do that?? Sorry if this should be a question of its own.

Comment: you should just ask your real question instead of having others answer theoretics. It's right there in the guidelines.

Comment: I have posted a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490194/how-to-implement-memcached-with-django-apis-while-underlying-database-objects